# Not able to use controls of the rigify rig

Tags: rigging

I've managed to parent the object with the rigify rig.
However, the only controls I'm able to use are the gumball.
I can rotate the rig, but the leg doesn't follow. Around the knee for instance.
I can drag the big handles at the end of the limbs, but my object just stretches out.
It is if it's just parented with the metarig, which it's not.

My result 1
[image: My result 1]

My result 2:
[image: My result 2]
Desired result. Screenshot from YouTube (where everything seems so simple):
[image: Desired result]

Comment: If you hit N in the 3D view with the rig selected you should see lots of settings for the rig including some labelled IK>FK. [This](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.0/addons/rigging/rigify/rig_features.html#ik-and-fk-switching) is the section in the Blender manual and there are many YT tutorials on using Rigify with human characters online.

Comment: Thank you! (I have to read and try later today before saying it's resolved.)